# android reset in app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

at the moment i testing the in app purchase of my app. for this i create a google account as test account.

i bought with my test account the in app option. now i would like to test this bough again, because i change something in my code.

how can i reset this in app purchase?
so i can do this buy again and again for testing?

at the moment i have to create every time a new google account and do a factory reset on my device.

this can't be the right way, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cancel your order. Use the link to "order history" you should have received via email, or go to the app listing in Google Play and cancel it from there.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#testing-purchases

"Canceling completed test purchases"

> In some cases, you might want to manually cancel a test purchase to continue testing. For canceling purchases, you have these options:
>
> - Wait for the transactions to expire—Google Play clears completed test purchases 14 days after their purchase date.
> - Cancel purchases manually—you can go to the Google payments merchant center, look up the transaction, and then cancel it. You can find transactions by looking up their order numbers.
>
> You can cancel test subscriptions purchases from the app page in the Play Store, or use the `cancel` method.

Comment: thanks, i canceled all Orders, but if i would like to buy this again, i get the message, that i bought this in app option before

Comment: Good stuff! Yes I believe there is some caching of your status

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is the following.

1. Go to Google Play Console ([www.play.google.com](http://www.play.google.com)) and sign in with your developer account.
2. Click on the 'Order Management' option on the left menu
3. Select the test 'order' that you would like to reset.
4. Click on Refund. Make sure to select 'Remove entitlement' checkbox.
   That is it. The refund will be provided in a few minutes. You can go to your app and buy the item again.